# Button click next array sentence (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

[image]I have a list of array that I want to show after each question is answered. It's gonna be like a never have I ever game I am build for building my skills. This ain't working at all why?

```js
var question = new Array()
<!-- list of 40 questions are here can't show them here right now -->

var intquestion_index = 0;

function displayQuestion() {
  if (intquestion_index == question.length) intquestion_index = 0;
  document.getElementById('questions').innerHTML;
  intquestion_index++;
}
```

```html
<div class="questions" id="questions">-</div>
<div class="answer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" id="btn-1" onclick="displayQuestion();">Hell yeah!</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" id="btn-2" onclick="displayQuestion();">Never ever ever</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" id="btn-3" onclick="displayQuestion();">Maybe</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `innerHTMl` Capitalization matters in programming (but what are you intending to do there, anyway?)

Comment: I want to get the div id and display the  next array question when one question is answered.

Comment: Why can't you show the array of questions?

Comment: They are long but I will update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you expect: move to next question on clicking one of the answer(button)

```js
var question = new Array();
question[0] = "question 1";
question[1] = "question 2";
question[2] = "question 3";
question[3] = "question 4";
// Below line will show first question on page load
document.getElementById('questions').innerHTML = question[0];  

// question at 0 is shown, so start index with 1
var question_index =1;

function displayQuestion() {  
  if (question_index == question.length)
  {
   question_index = 0;
  }
  document.getElementById('questions').innerHTML = question[question_index];  
  question_index++;
}
```

```html
<div class="questions" id="questions">-</div>
<div class="answer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" id="btn-1" onclick="displayQuestion();">Hell yeah!</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" id="btn-2" onclick="displayQuestion();">Never ever ever</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" id="btn-3" onclick="displayQuestion();">Maybe</button>
</div>
```